# jquery not clicking button on load of page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, button

I have a simple aspx page.  After loading the page I want a button to be pressed.

Here is the button that I want to click:

```
<asp:Button class="js-modal js-prevent-bg-click inline" id="invisibleSelectProducer" href="#" runat="server" Text="Select Producer"></asp:Button>
```

Here is the jquery that I have added that (I would have thought) should click the button once the page is finished loading:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       console.log($("#invisibleSelectProducer"));
        $("#invisibleSelectProducer").click();
    });
</script>
```

Am I missing something completely obvious?  Even the log that I added (above) logs the button object that I want to click.  But the code immediately following does nothing.

EDIT
After trying Mike123's suggestion, I have the following code.  It still does not work though.  Once again, the console will let me see the button object (so I know it is rendered) but the .click() is not firing off once the page loads.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       console.log($("#<%=invisibleSelectProducer.ClientID%>"));
        $("#<%=invisibleSelectProducer.ClientID%>").click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Adrift.  Was in the middle of adding better code sections, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side control id of invisibleSelectProducer will be different on the client, you should either reference as either one by client id or class name

```
$("#<%=invisibleSelectProducer.ClientID%>").click();
```

or

```
$(".js-modal").click();
```

.js-modal is the class you have in your markup, but you might want to use custom one

Comment: Sorry, i was on the dude version of maternity leave last week :)  I have changed my code to reflect what you suggested and it still does not click on page load.

Comment: Holt, have you made a progress? The click event may not work if the button is hidden. You think it could be the case?

Comment: I was using a custom modal class that someone else creates.  Turns out...they had logic that prevented the modal from being clicked until after the page's init was completely done.  Rather dumb...but I figured a way around it.

Comment: Even though this suggestion didn't help me in my particular issue...it obviously is the correct way to click a button.